# Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 and WiX?

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2010

Has anybody been using WiX with 2010?  I'm not able to get my install projects to work in 2010 and I can't find any info on getting this to work/future plans for support.

Comment: This may seem obvious but has to be asked. Did you install the WiX 3.5 support for 2010? There was a new one built 3 days ago. http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.1023.0/

Comment: Something tells me you should move this comment to an answer... Checking on it now.

Comment: I have added an answer that covers the gist of the comment. :) I hope it works for you.

Comment: @Russell Not sure why I did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the latest build of WiX 3.5. This is the version that supports VS2010. I don't know if it has been updated for the beta2 release, but there was [a new one built 3 days ago](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.1023.0/).

**EDIT**: The link above will not work for Visual Studio 2010 post-Beta. For later releases of Visual Studio 2010, use the latest release:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/

and select the latest version.

Comment: I didn't remove the old link as the question from the PO states the beta version of Visual Studio. However this tripped me up in my quest, so hopefully it will help those in the future. :)

Comment: You will also need to install the Project Aggregator 2: http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html

Comment: @Russell: The project aggregator is not required for 2010 - that was for 2005 only.

Answer (score 2):

which version of Wix are you using? last I checked, there was some compatibility issues with wix >=3, votive, and visual studio.

you might have to get a custom build of votive that will load on 2010.

Comment: Tried the latest official version, but that won't install if you don't have 2k5 or 2k8 installed.

Comment: @Will: you need the 3.5 release for 2010 support - it's still in beta.

Comment: Ya.  Added an answer with what I did to get it working.  Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 26, this is what I had to do to get it working:

Download latest of 3.5 http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.1023.0/

I snagged Wix35_x64.msi, you grab the other if you run 32bit.  I'm not sure what the other (less obvious) files are for (I'm looking at you, ProjectAggregator2).

After installation, Wix projects load (yay!) but don't build (boo) with an error about the path for Candle.EXE being invalid.  Apparently, its still looking for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3" on my system.

Created this directory and copied the contents of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v35" into it.

Now, apart from some build errors due to changes in some of the $vars, it works.

Answer (score 0):

We added support for Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 in last Friday's build. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2009/10/30/wix-v3-5-supports-visual-studio-2010-beta-2/.